Attempted to load @next/swc-win32-x64-msvc, but an error occurred:
I tried to run my nextjs app but it keeps failing with this error:
nextjs@0.1.0 dev                                   > next dev                                                                                                  ▲ Next.js 14.2.8                                     - Local:        http://localhost:3000                - Environments: .env                                                                                     ✓ Starting...                                        ⚠ Attempted to load @next/swc-win32-x64-msvc, but an error occurred: \?\C:\Users\Wyteshadow\Desktop\projects\duet-ai-build\node_modules@next\swc-win32-x64-msvc\next-swc.win32-x64-msvc.node is not a valid Win32 application.                                        \?\C:\Users\Wyteshadow\Desktop\projects\duet-ai-build\node_modules@next\swc-win32-x64-msvc\next-swc.win32-x64-msvc.node                                       ⨯ Failed to load SWC binary for win32/x64, see more info here: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/failed-loading-swc
I tried removing node modules, yes am using win32 x64 node versiom.
i also add the babel config and tried disabling minifyswc but it still didnt work

Hi, please see formatting help
